# Powershell Foreach-Object behaves abnormaly on null values

Tags: powershell, foreach, null

Foreach-Object is treating $null value differently in different cases. What is the ideal behavior?

```
## Case 1: 
 $someitem = $null 
 if($null -EQ $someitem) { write-host "true" } # prints true
 $someitem | ForEach-Object { write-host "hello" } # prints hello
## Case 2 :
 $items = Get-ChildItem -Path "someNotExistingPath" # throws error
 if($null -EQ $items) { write-host "true"} # prints true
 $items | ForEach-Object { write-host "hello" } # prints nothing
```

The expected behavior would have been that both foreach-object print "hello", but in the case when we have tried to assign some value to $items, it behaves unually inside foreach loop

Comment: `$someitem` is `$null` in the singular form (the same as an array of 1), `$items` is an empty array and so `$items | ForEach-Object` has 0 elements to iterate over

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I traced the differences between `$items | forEach-Object { Write-host "hello"}` and `$null | ForEach-Object { Write-Host "hello"}` via `Trace-Command`.

```
   PS C:>Trace-Command -Name parameterbinding -Expression {  $items | ForEach-Object { write-host "hello" } } -PSHost
   DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Out-Null]
   DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Out-Null]
   DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Out-Null]
   ....


   PS C:> Trace-Command -Name parameterbinding -Expression {  $null | ForEach-Object { write-host "hello" } } -PSHost
   DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [ForEach-Object]
   DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [ForEach-Object]
   DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [ write-host "hello" ] to parameter [Process]
   DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Binding collection parameter Process: argument type [ScriptBlock], parameter type [System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock[]], collection type Array, element type [System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock], no
```

It seems that `$items` points to the `Out-Null` cmdlet, which is shown via:

```
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Out-Null]
```

So it seems that `Get-ChildItem` returns a reference to `Out-Null` in case of an error. If you compare this to `$null | ForEach-Object ...` you'll that the `ForEach-Object` will be invoked directly:

```
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [ForEach-Object]
```

What's also interesting, if you use `ForEach-Object` with the `-InputObject` parameter the code works as requested:

```
 PS C:> Trace-Command -Name parameterbinding -Expression {  ForEach-Object -InputObject $items -Process { write-host "hello" } } -PSHost
 DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [ForEach-Object]
 DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [] to parameter [InputObject]
```

So my "guess" is the following. In case of an error (of `Get-ChildItem`) you won't that below code prints an output:

```
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem -Path "notExisting" | ForEach-Object { Write-Host "found" }
```

That makes perfectly sense, `Get-ChildItem` "calls" `Out-Null` which will clear the pipeline, which will break the pipeline chain (= if nothing is found, nothing shall be printed).

Base on that, this call statement `$items = Get-ChildItem -Path "someNotExistingPath"` is invoked, but `Get-ChildItem` returns a null type that is not equal to `$null`. When performing this code `if($null -EQ $items)` PowerShell will more or less perform a implicit cast of the `Get-ChildItem`-null-type to `$null`. When it comes to this call `$items | ForEach-Object`, nothing else should be send to the pipeline since `$items` contains the reulst of `Out-Null`.

UPDATE:

In the meanwhile @iRon also added a duplicate link, which explains the [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30016949/why-and-how-are-these-two-null-values-different). I'll keep the answer since this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30016949/why-and-how-are-these-two-null-values-different) doesn't show the usage of `Trace-Command`. Hope thats ok for the community.

Hope that helps.