# Why is piping null to set-variable causing different outcomes?

Tags: powershell, null

When using set-variable I am seeing different behaviors when piping a null value to it.

In the first setup, we create a variable, and overwriting it with null, so far so good.

```
# Setup 1: Passing a null value
$test1 = "test1" 
$null | set-variable test1
Write-Host "It is: $test1" # "It is: "

# $null.gettype()
# You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

However in the second setup, to my believe, we are also overwriting it with null, however the variable is not changed.

```
# Setup 2: Passing a null value by deducting a list
$testList = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.ArrayList'
$testList.Add("test")

$test2 = "test2" 
$testList | Select-Object -SkipLast 1 | set-variable test2
Write-Host "It is: $test2" # "It is: test2"

# $($testList | Select-Object -SkipLast 1).gettype()
# You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

Why is the first setup overwriting the variable and the second setup is not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me add some **background information** to [Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76631170/45375):

Indeed, PowerShell has **two types of null values**:

- The ***scalar* null**, so to speak, analogous to `null` in C# and other languages, for instance, which is the value of the [automatic **`$null`** variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#null).

  - You can think of it as **placeholder for a *missing object***.
  - **`$null` is sent through the pipeline as-is**.
  - Curiously, the same is *not* true for using `$null` as the input to a [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) *statement*: `foreach ($val in $null) { 'here!' }` produces *no* output, implying that the loop is never entered.
  - `$null` is what trying to access *nonexistent variables* evaluates to, unfortunately,<sup>[1]</sup> but its explicit use - other than in *tests* such as `$null -eq $value` - is rare in PowerShell.
- The ***enumerable* null,** so to speak, which is a PowerShell-specific concept:

  - You can think of it as an **enumerable that *enumerates nothing***.
  - Sadly, this special value has no official name as of this writing, thought it is often called **"Automation null"** and sometimes "empty null".
    Also, there is ***no* automatic variable for it**, i.e. there is *no* analog to the automatic `$null` variable for the *scalar* null.
  - Given that the enumerable null is **technically the "return value" of commands that produce *no output***, the simplest way to obtain it is to execute `$nullEnum = & {}`, i.e. to execute an empty script block. Specifically, the enumerable null is the [`[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull.Value) singleton (the documentation link provides no meaningful information).
  - In a ***pipeline*** (e.g., `$value | Write-Output`)...

    - ... the enumerable null **behaves like a *collection with no elements***, which means that, given that collections are *enumerated* in the pipeline (have their elements sent *one by one*), *no data* is sent through the pipeline, which is (typically) a *no-op*: the **commands in subsequent pipeline segments receive *no input* to operate on**.
    - Note that the automatic enumeration logic also applies to the [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement and to the LHS of comparison operators (which act as *filters* with enumerable LHS values); providing the enumerable null as input to `switch` effectively *skips* the statement (e.g. `switch (& {}) { default { 'never get here' } }`); whether the enumerable null is treated as an enumerable as the LHS of a comparison operation depends on the specific operator; `-match` treats it as an enumerable (`(& {}) -match ''` -> empty array), `-eq` does not (`(& {}) -eq ''` -> `$false`)
  - In an ***expression*** (e.g, `$null -eq $value`)...

    - ... the enumerable null **behaves like `$null`**
    - Additionally, when **passing the enumerable null *as an argument*** (parameter value) to a command, ***conversion to `$null`* invariably happens** - see [GitHub issue #9150](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9150)

The above explains the difference between `$null | Set-Variable test1` (variable `test` is set to the `$null` value received via the pipeline) and `& {} | Set-Variable test2` (variable `test2` is never created or updated, because `Set-Variable` receives no input; your `Select-Object -SkipLast 1` call on the 1-element input collection produced *no output*, and therefore emitted the enumerable null).

See also:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41568525/45375) also touches on *historic* aspects of `$null` vs. `[System.Management.Automation.Null]` handling, covering the behavioral changes that happened in the transition from v2 to v3+.
- [This comment on GitHub issue #9150](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9150#issuecomment-473743805) summarizes how the null dichotomy *could* be handled in a consistent manner, *if backward compatibility weren't a concern*.

---

**Given the fundamental behavioral differences**, it is important:

- to **properly *document*** these two null types, as well as **give the enumerable null an *official name***.
- to **make it easy to *programmatically distinguish*** the two types.

As of this writing (PowerShell 7.3.6), neither requirement is met.

**Detecting the enumerable null** is currently cumbersome and obscure:

```bash
$value = & {} # Obtain the enumerable null.

# Without the `-and $value.psobject` part, you couldn't distinguish 
# $null from the enumerable null.
$isNullEnumerable = 
  $null -eq $value -and $value.psobject
```

While `$null -eq $value` returns `$true` for *both* a true `$null` and the enumerable null, `$value.psobject` only returns a value for the enumerable null (which, when coerced to a Boolean, evaluates to `$true`). The reason is that, unlike `$null`, the enumerable null is technically *an object* and therefore returns a value for the [intrinsic `psobject` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#object-views).

As a result of the discussion in [GitHub issue #13465](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13465), **the following improvement has been *green-lit*, but is *yet to be implemented***:

```bash
# NOT YET IMPLEMENTED as of PowerShell 7.3.6
$isNullEnumerable = 
  $value -is [System.Management.Automation.Null]
```

That is, you'll be able to use `-is`, the [type(-inheritance) / interface test operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Operators) with the yet-to-be-introduced `[System.Management.Automation.Null]` type, which will supersede the "pubternal" `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]` type.<sup>[2]</sup>

Unfortunately, also introducing a *type accelerator* - which would simplify the test to `$value -is [AutomationNull]` - was decided *against*.

---

<sup>[1] This default value is unfortunate, because it means that `$noSuchVariable | ...` *sends `$null`* through the pipeline. If the default were the "enumerable null"  ("Automation null", `[System.Management.Automation.Null]::Value`) instead, no data would be sent, the way the `foreach` *statement* already - but surprisingly - handles `$null` (too). With the enumerable null as the default, there would be no need for the asymmetry between pipeline and `foreach` behavior, and `$null` could *consistently* be preserved as such.</sup>

<sup>[2] This change involves more than just a new *type name*: the new type's singleton (`[System.Management.Automation.Null]::Value`), i.e. the actual enumerable null, will then be *of that same type*, whereas the current singleton (`[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value`) is of a *different* type, namely just `[psobject]` - see [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9997#issuecomment-580743572) for details.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty much the difference between `AutomationNull` and `$null`. See [**Everything you wanted to know about `$null`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-null?view=powershell-7.3), great in depth article.

```
$test2 = 'test2'
& { } | Set-Variable test2 # AutomationNull, Process block does not run!
$test2 # Outputs: test2
$null | Set-Variable test2 # $null is not AutomationNull, it does get piped
$test2 # Outputs: $null
```

You can use this example to get a better understanding of what is going on. As you may see, the [`process` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.2#process) of our function is never invoked when `AutomationNull` is piped through.

```
function Set-Var {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [object] $Value,

        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)]
        [string] $Name
    )

    process {
        $PSCmdlet.WriteVerbose("Setting value [$Value] to PSVariable [$Name]")
        $psvar = $PSCmdlet.SessionState.PSVariable.Get($Name)
        $psvar.Value = $Value
        $PSCmdlet.SessionState.PSVariable.Set($psvar)
    }
}

$test = 'hello'
$null | Set-Var test -Verbose
# VERBOSE: Setting value [] to PSVariable [test]
$test # Outputs: $null
'foo' | Set-Var test -Verbose
# VERBOSE: Setting value [foo] to PSVariable [test]
$test # Outputs: foo
& { } | Set-Var test -Verbose
# No verbose output, meaning the Process Block was never invoked!
$test # Outputs: foo
```