# PowerShell - Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Division'

Tags: powershell

I have a script that works fine on some machines,(all machines have same,5.1 Powershell version)

Script calculates CPU usage percentage for windows services

```
$cpu   = Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor -Property NumberOfCores, NumberOfLogicalProcessors
     # Define the number of top services to display
     $services = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service | Where-Object { $_.State -eq 'Running' } | Sort-Object -Property ProcessId | ForEach-Object {
        $process = Get-Process -Id $_.ProcessId
        if ($process.StartTime -gt 0){
           $ts = (New-TimeSpan -Start $process.StartTime -ea si).TotalSeconds
           $cpuUsagePercentage = [math]::Round($process.CPU *100 / $ts /  $cpu.numberoflogicalprocessors, 2)
        }
        else{
           $cpuUsagePercent = 0
        }
       
        $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CpuUsage" -Value $cpuUsagePercentage
        $_
     } | Sort-Object -Property CpuUsage -Descending | Select-Object Name, ProcessId, CpuUsage -First 3
```

Script fails on this line with error from the title `[System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Division'`

```
$cpuUsagePercentage = [math]::Round($process.CPU *100 / $ts /  $cpu.numberoflogicalprocessors, 2)
```

I debugged this and put breakpoint on above line and values are:

```
$process.CPU=699
$ts=737146,1126995
$cpu.numberoflogicalprocessors=1
```

No idea why it works on some machine while it fails on other

$cpu variable:

```
__GENUS                   : 2
__CLASS                   : Win32_Processor
__SUPERCLASS              :
__DYNASTY                 :
__RELPATH                 :
__PROPERTY_COUNT          : 2
__DERIVATION              : {}
__SERVER                  :
__NAMESPACE               :
__PATH                    :
NumberOfCores             : 1
NumberOfLogicalProcessors : 1
PSComputerName            :

__GENUS                   : 2
__CLASS                   : Win32_Processor
__SUPERCLASS              :
__DYNASTY                 :
__RELPATH                 :
__PROPERTY_COUNT          : 2
__DERIVATION              : {}
__SERVER                  :
__NAMESPACE               :
__PATH                    :
NumberOfCores             : 1
NumberOfLogicalProcessors : 1
PSComputerName            :

__GENUS                   : 2
__CLASS                   : Win32_Processor
__SUPERCLASS              :
__DYNASTY                 :
__RELPATH                 :
__PROPERTY_COUNT          : 2
__DERIVATION              : {}
__SERVER                  :
__NAMESPACE               :
__PATH                    :
NumberOfCores             : 1
NumberOfLogicalProcessors : 1
PSComputerName            :

__GENUS                   : 2
__CLASS                   : Win32_Processor
__SUPERCLASS              :
__DYNASTY                 :
__RELPATH                 :
__PROPERTY_COUNT          : 2
__DERIVATION              : {}
__SERVER                  :
__NAMESPACE               :
__PATH                    :
NumberOfCores             : 1
NumberOfLogicalProcessors : 1
PSComputerName            :

__GENUS                   : 2
__CLASS                   : Win32_Processor
__SUPERCLASS              :
__DYNASTY                 :
__RELPATH                 :
__PROPERTY_COUNT          : 2
__DERIVATION              : {}
__SERVER                  :
__NAMESPACE               :
__PATH                    :
NumberOfCores             : 1
NumberOfLogicalProcessors : 1
PSComputerName            :

__GENUS                   : 2
__CLASS                   : Win32_Processor
__SUPERCLASS              :
__DYNASTY                 :
__RELPATH                 :
__PROPERTY_COUNT          : 2
__DERIVATION              : {}
__SERVER                  :
__NAMESPACE               :
__PATH                    :
NumberOfCores             : 1
NumberOfLogicalProcessors : 1
PSComputerName            :
```

Comment: Error indicates that this host has 2 or more CPUs, meaning `$cpu.numberoflogicalprocessors` is an array

Comment: ahh...yes, $cpu shows  6 "arrays". One for each CPU's, while on working machine, shows only 1 element,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the problem is that you **cannot apply `/` (the [division operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arithmetic_Operators)) to *array* operands**, and that is what the error message is trying to express (try `2 / @(1, 2)` or `@(1, 2) / 2` to provoke the error), and the solution is to use *single* numbers only.

To complement [your own effective solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76788911/45375) with simpler alternatives, using [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance) in lieu of the (soft-)deprecated `Get-WmiObject` cmdlet<sup>[1]</sup> - this will return objects of a different type, but with *more* information (properties) about your CPUs.

###### How to extract only the *first* object from a command's output:

- With **[`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)**, in the *pipeline*:

  ```bash
  $cpu = 
    Get-CimInstance –class Win32_processor -Property NumberOfCores, NumberOfLogicalProcessors |
    Select-Object -First 1
  ```
- With an **array [index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#index-operator--)** *expression*, applied to an [array subexpression (`@(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--)):

  ```bash
  # Note: (...) will often do instead of @(...), but the latter is more robust.
  $cpu = @(
    Get-CimInstance –class Win32_processor -Property NumberOfCores, NumberOfLogicalProcessors
  )[0]
  ```

Note:

- While your particular `Get-WmiObject` / `Get-CimInstance` by definition returns *at least 1* object (unless a catastrophic failure occurs), both solutions above **can result in *no* output in principle**, but there's a **subtle distinction**.

  - An index *expression* such as `@(...)[0]` will return `$null` if no element exists at the specified index.

    - *Caveat*: If the command has no output, this will actually *fail* if [`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) is set to `-Version 3` or above (by default, *no* strict mode is in effect).
  - By contrast, if a *command* such as `Select-Object` produces no output, what is *technically* returned is an "enumerable null" ("Automation null"), a special singleton value that behaves like `$null` in *expression* contexts, but behaves like an *empty collection* (enumerable) in enumeration contexts, such as the pipeline.
  - This distinction *typically* doesn't matter, but *can* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76631985/45375) for details.
- There's also a **difference with respect output *timing* and output *collection***:

  - As a *command* that operates in PowerShell's [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipelines), `Select-Object` receives and outputs objects *one by one*, a process known as *streaming*.

    - That is, as soon as `Select-Object` receives the *first* input object emitted by `Get-CimInstance`, it emits it, and then terminates the `Get-CimInstance` call (as well as any other so-called upstream commands in the same pipeline) given that only *one* object is needed.
  - By contrast, `@(...)[0]`, due to the indexing being an *expression*, requires collecting the output from `...` *in full, up front* in memory, as an array (of type `[object[]]`), to which index `[0]` is applied.

    - That is, `Get-CimInstance` must run *to completion*, and all its output objects must be collected first, before the first object is extracted.
    - A note on using array indexing with `@(...)`, the [array subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) vs. just the `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--):

      - `@(...)` acts like an array "guarantor": If the output from `...` happens to be a *single object*, PowerShell wraps it in a *single-element* array, so you are guaranteed to be dealing with an *array*.
      - While PowerShell's unified handling of scalars and arrays - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44035802/45375) - often makes this unnecessary (e.g., `(42)[0]` yields `42`, just like `@(42)[0]`), there are *exceptions*, which makes `@(...)[0]` the only *robust* choice:

        - If a single object *itself* has an indexer - which is notably true for *strings* (`[string]`), using `(...)[0]` will invoke that object's indexer instead (e.g., while `@(Write-Output foo)[0]` is `'foo'`, `(Write-Output foo)[0]` is `f`(!), because the expression is equivalent to `'foo'[0]`)
        - It isn't always obvious which objects have their own indexers (e.g, `[xml]`, though a *numeric* index should arguably still work - see [GitHub issue #11923](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11923)), and other factors too can interfere with PowerShell's "scalar indexing"; case in point: applying `(...)[0]` to your `Get-WmiObject` call yields *no output* (whereas it does work with `Get-CimInstance`).
  - **Tradeoffs**:

    - While using array indexing is more concise and often performs better (not in this case), it comes at the expense of increased memory consumption and potentially delayed to-display output.
    - Streaming output can keep memory use constant (assuming that output isn't collected in full afterwards) or use less memory (if the collected output amounts to a *filtered* subset of the input data), but is generally slower, due to the overhead of one-by-one processing.

---

<sup>[1] The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) v6+, where all future effort will go, doesn't even *have* them anymore. Note that WMI still *underlies* the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Santiago Squarzon's suggestion, added a check if $cpu variable is array, if yes, select first element.Noticed that for every element of array, getting same value for NumberoOfLogicalProcessors

```
$cpu   = Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor -Property NumberOfCores, NumberOfLogicalProcessors
     if ($cpu -is[array]){
       $cpu = $cpu[0]
     }
# rest of the code is same
```