# Powershell array with null value sometimes empty

Tags: arrays, powershell, null, select-object

This happens with Powershell version `5.1.19041.3031`.

I found something very weird that I cannot explain:

```
$x = $null
'x is null: {0}' -f ($null -eq $x)
'array containing x has size {0}' -f @($x).Count

$y = $null | Select-Object
'y is null: {0}' -f ($null -eq $y)
'array containing y has size {0}' -f @($y).Count
```

This outputs the following:

```
x is null: True
array containing x has size 1
y is null: True
array containing y has size 0
```

It looks like $x and $y are both $null but a different one. On both I cannot call `.GetType()` yet they behave differently.

---

The real problem I was trying to solve is this:

```
$x = (Get-Bla).Name
Compare-Object @($x) @() # moans about $x being null sometimes when Get-Bla returns nothing
```

If I use `$x = (Get-Bla).Name | Select-Object` it fixes the problem but I couldn't understand the difference `Select-Object` was doing in this case.

Comment: See: [`Empty Null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-null#empty-null), does this answer your question: [Why is piping null to set-variable causing different outcomes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76631985/1701026)?

Comment: X and Y processing is different.  Y you are using Select-Object.  If something is null why are you testing the length of a null object?

Comment: To summarize: In addition to `$null`, PowerShell has a "null enumerable" aka "Automation Null" (the [`[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull.Value) singleton), which represent the _absence of output_ from a command. _In expressions_, it behaves the same as `$null`, but it acts differently _in a pipeline_, where it acts like an _empty collection_ and therefore sends nothing through it.