# Why does running `Get-Content` return a null-valued expression?

Tags: powershell, null, expression

I run this command:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -file | ForEach-Object { (Get-Content $_).Replace('hi there','hello') | Set-Content $_ }
```

and get this error:

```
InvalidOperation: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
InvalidOperation: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

Do you know why is that?

Comment: this can trigger due to unfortunate enumeration if the file has no contents (an empty text file). use `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.FullName).Replace(...` instead of `(Get-Content $_)...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) notes - perhaps surprisingly - using [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) to read an *empty* file (`0` bytes) outputs `$null` (irrespective of whether you also use `-Raw`).<sup>[1]</sup>

Calling *any* method on `$null` results in the error you saw.

A simple solution is to filter out empty files, and there is no point in performing any replacements on them anyway:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File |
  Where-Object Length -gt 0 |
  ForEach-Object {
    ($_ | Get-Content -Raw).Replace('hi there','hello') | 
      Set-Content -NoNewLine -LiteralPath $_.FullName
  }
```

Note the following additional improvements:

- `$_ | Get-Content` is equivalent to `Get-Content -LiteralPath $_.FullName` and ensures that each input file is passed by its full path and that the path is interpreted *literally* (verbatim).
- `-Raw` ensures that the file content is read *as a single (multiline) string*, which speeds up the replacements.
- `-NoNewLine` prevents `Set-Content` from appending an extra newline to (potentially modified) file content.

---

<sup>[1] Technically, *not* using `-Raw` emits an "enumerable null", the special `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value` singleton that indicates lack of output from a command. However, in the context of *expressions*, such as method calls, this value is treated the same as `$null` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76631985/45375) for more information.

*With* `-Raw`, you could argue that the *empty string* rather than `$null` should be returned, as suggested in [GitHub issue #3911](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3911).</sup>

Comment: what does the `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value` mean? What is the thing in the bracket called? What is this syntax?

Comment: @Ooker: `[<type name>]` is a PowerShell _type literal_ - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66996505/45375). `::` is the [static member-access operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#static-member-operator-). As for the meaning of this special singleton: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76631985/45375).