# What is a "Scalar" in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, collections, terminology, definition, scalar

The term `scalar` is often used in PowerShell issues and documentation along with e.g. the [about_Comparison_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) document. I think, I do have an *abstract* understanding of its meaning (in fact I am using the word myself quite often) but I am unsure about the *concrete* PowerShell definition.

##### Scalar data type ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_processor#Scalar_data_type)):

> A scalar data type, or just scalar, is any non-[composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) [value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)).

##### Converting from scalar types ([about_Booleans](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_booleans#converting-from-scalar-types))

> A scalar type is an atomic quantity that can hold only one value at a time.

But how exactly would I (script wise) check for a scalar in PowerShell?
E.g. should a [DateTime Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime) and a collection with single item (as `[Int[]]1`) considered a `scalar`?
There is no concrete scalar type or interface definition, to do something like:

```
If ($Something -is [Scalar]) { ...
```

So, I guess the concrete PowerShell definition is something like:

```
$IsScalar =
    ($_ -isnot [Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]) -and
    ($_ -isnot [ComponentModel.Component]) -and           
    ($_ -isnot [Collections.IDictionary]) -and  # Probably covered by ICollection
    ($_ -isnot [Collections.ICollection])
```

But not sure if that actually covers it.

Comment: In the context of that documentation I think it just means “a type that doesn’t implement any of collection interface that Powershell recognises” - it’s a bit confusing because it suggests a DateTime *is* a scalar, but from a more formal / mathematical perspective it’s not really a scalar.

Comment: The key here is that a scalar is a one-dimensional data type. Therefore, you can define a comparison operator along that single dimension. DateTime is just a time representation (ticks since 0001-01-01 CE) and therefore really a scalar. `Range` would be an example of a non-scalar object (since it has both begin and end)

Comment: @MSalter, thanks for your comment. What about a `[PSCustomObject]`? My first thought would be that this is also a scalar, but the fact that it might contain an undefined number of properties, lets me think otherwise...

Comment: The formal definition of a scalar is a non-composite value - ie. something that represents a discrete value in and of itself that can't be atomized further (eg. numerical primitives and strings). In the context of PowerShell (and similar languages) the definition is sometimes stretched to mean "a single value" in opposition to _enumerables_ (what @mclayton said basically).

Comment: This itself is not a useful comment as such -- but this is a really good SO question :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add to the helpful information in your question and in the comments:

There are ***two*, context-dependent definitions of what you might loosely call "scalar" in PowerShell**, and **while they *technically* differ, the difference *typically* doesn't matter**:

- Note:

  - What the two definitions have **in common** is the following ***loose* definition: a "scalar" is any object that *isn't primarily a collection of other objects***.
- **In *enumeration contexts***, notably in the *pipeline*, and on the *LHS* of *comparison operators*, among others:

  - A **"scalar"** is **any object that cannot be or isn't *auto-enumerated***; that is, it is treated as a *single object*.
  - The behavior is ***primarily*** based on whether a type implements the **[`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IEnumerable)** interface, with *selective, hard-coded exceptions*; an **informal summary** is:

    - **.NET enumerables *except* strings, dictionaries, and XML nodes** are ***auto-enumerated***.
    - **Additionally** - even though they are not enumerables per se -  so are **data tables and enumerators.**
    - Any other object is a "scalar", i.e. processed *as itself*.
  - See the next section for details.
- **In *to-Boolean coercions (conversions)***:

  - A **"scalar"** is **any object that *isn't list-like***, as exclusively determined by whether its type implements the **[`IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IList)** interface.<sup>[1]</sup>
  - A **quick summary of the to-Boolean coercion (conversion) logic**, which applies to *implicit* coercions, such as in conditionals, as well as to *explicit* ones with a `[bool]` cast):

    - List-like objects that contain *no* elements are *always `$false`*, those that contain only *one* object (element) are treated *as that object* (see below), whereas those with *two or more* elements are *always `$true`*, irrespective of what elements they contain; e.g., `[bool] @($false)` is `$false`, but `[bool] @($false, $false)` is `$true`
    - The following yield `$false`:

      - A numeric `0` value, regardless of the specific numeric type
      - The *empty string* (e.g. `''`)
      - `$null`, including the "enumerable null", i.e. the special singleton<sup>[2]</sup> that signals "no output" from *commands*, but is treated like `$null` in *expressions*; e.g. both `[bool] $null` and `[bool] (Get-ChildItem NoSuchFiles*)` yield `$false`.
    - Any other object yields `$true`, notably including:

      - any *nonempty string*, *irrespective of its content*, e.g. `[bool] 'foo'` and `[bool] 'false'`
      - any non-string, non-[.NET primitive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isprimitive#System_Type_IsPrimitive) instance, e.g.
        `[bool] [pscustomobject] @{}`,

        - including any *nonempty list-like* object that happens to be the *only element of* a list-like object; in other words: the treat-a-single-element-list-as-that-element logic is *not* applied *recursively*; e.g.
          `[bool] (, @($false))` is `$true` (but a nested *empty* list is `$false`, e.g. `[bool] (, @())`)

**The - comparatively *rare* - scenarios where the two definitions of "scalar" *do* make a difference**:

- Since the `IList` interface (ultimately) *derives* from `IEnumerable`, and none of the `IEnumerable` exceptions in enumerable contexts implement `IList`, the difference comes down to the following scenarios:
- [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IEnumerable)-implementing types that do not also implement [`IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IList), e.g. the objects returned by [`[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Range()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Linq.Enumerable.Range):

  ```bash
   # NON-scalar in the pipeline:
   # Auto-enumeration -> nothing is sent through the pipeline,
   # because the enumeration is *empty*
   [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Range(0, 0) | Measure-Object # -> 0

   # SCALAR in to-Boolean conversion:
   # The object doesn't implement [IList], and since it is
   # not a .NET primitive type, it is implicitly $true.
   [bool] [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Range(0, 0)  # -> !! $true

   # Note that if you force enumeration via @(...),
   # which collects the enumerated objects in an [object[]] array,
   # the [IList] logic does apply:
   [bool] @([System.Linq.Enumerable]::Range(0, 0)) # -> $false
  ```
- [`IEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IEnumerator)-implementing types; e.g., the object returned by an explicit `.GetEnumerator()` call:

  ```bash
   # NON-scalar in the pipeline:
   # Auto-enumeration -> nothing is sent through the pipeline.
   @{}.GetEnumerator() | Measure-Object # -> 0

   # SCALAR in to-Boolean conversion:
   # [IEnumerator] doesn't implement [IList], and since it is
   # not a .NET primitive type, it is implicitly $true.
   [bool] @{}.GetEnumerator()  # -> !! $true
  ```
- [`System.Data.DataTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Data.DataTable), the only non-`IEnumerable` type that PowerShell auto-enumerates in enumeration contexts.

  ```bash
   # NON-scalar in the pipeline:
   # Auto-enumeration -> nothing is sent through the pipeline,
   # because the data table has *no rows*.
   [System.Data.DataTable]::new() | Measure-Object # -> 0

   # SCALAR in to-Boolean conversion:
   # [System.Data.DataTable] doesn't implement [IList], 
   # and since it is not a .NET primitive type, it is implicitly $true.
   [bool] [System.Data.DataTable]::new()  # -> !! $true
  ```

---

##### "Scalars" in *enumeration contexts*:

**Enumeration contexts** are:

- The **[pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipelines)** - as also implicitly used by a *single command*, e.g. `Get-ChildItem $HOME`
- Select **operators**:

  - The *LHS* operands of [*comparison operators*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#common-features).
  - The relevant operand of the [*containment operators*, `-in` and `-contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#containment-operators)
  - [`$(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), the subexpression operator and [`@(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), the array subexpression operator. The reason that these are enumeration contexts is that they are in essence *nested pipelines*.
- The inputs to select [**language statements**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Language_Keywords) (keyword-based statements) (represented as `…` below):

  - [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) (`foreach ($elem in …) { <# body #> }`)
  - [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) (`switch (…) { <# body #> }`)

In any such enumeration context, **a "scalar" is any object that cannot be or isn't *auto-enumerated***.

**Auto-enumeration** means:

- Instead of processing the object *itself*, process the objects *its enumeration* returns, one by one, (ultimately) via the `IEnumerable` interface (e.g., enumeration of an [*array*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Array) returns *its elements*).

That is:

- It doesn't matter whether a "scalar" object is a composite value (has properties) or not (e.g. a [.NET primitive type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isprimitive#System_Type_IsPrimitive) such as `[int]`).
- While whether an instance's type implements the **[`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IEnumerable) interface** (which makes them enumerable *on demand* from *.NET's* perspective) is the *basis* for PowerShell's decision whether to auto-enumerator or not, there are ***selective, hard-coded exceptions***, detailed below.

  - To get PowerShell to enumerate instances of such types *on demand*, a prominent example of which are [*hashtables*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables), their `.GetEnumerator()` method must be called explicitly; e.g., the following enumerates the key-value pairs ([`System.Collections.DictionaryEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.DictionaryEntry) instances) that make up the sample hashtable and stringifies each; without `.GetEnumerator()`, the hashtable instance *as a whole* would be sent to the pipeline:
    `@{ foo = 1; bar = 2 }.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object ToString`
  - The fact that this works implies yet another non-"scalar": any object whose type implements the **[`IEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IEnumerator)** interface, as implemented by `IEnumerable`-implementing types.<sup>[3]</sup>

The following function encapsulates the **exact logic PowerShell uses to determine automatic enumerability**;<sup>[4]</sup> it accepts any object and indicates whether PowerShell would auto-enumerate it in enumeration contexts.

```bash
function Test-Enumerability {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [object] $InputObject
  )

  (
    $InputObject -is    [System.Collections.IEnumerable] -and
    $InputObject -isnot [System.Collections.IDictionary] -and
    $InputObject -isnot [string]                         -and 
    $InputObject -isnot [System.Xml.XmlNode]
  ) -or
    $InputObject -is    [System.Data.DataTable]          -or
    $InputObject -is    [System.Collections.IEnumerator]
  
}
```

An **informal summary** of the above:

- .NET enumerables *except* strings, dictionaries,<sup>[5]</sup> and XML nodes are auto-enumerated.
- Additionally - even though they are not enumerables per se - the following are automatically enumerated too:

  - data tables, by their rows (`.Rows` property)
  - enumerators (i.e. objects that *enumerate* enumerables)

---

<sup>[1] Here's the link to the [source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/9383f554a2c719af88010a66e2a283fa93c07db9/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/LanguagePrimitives.cs#L1011C20-L1011C20), as of this writing (this logic is highly unlikely to change, however).</sup>

<sup>[2] This special singleton is [`[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull.Value); for more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76631985/45375).</sup>

<sup>[3] The same applies to types implementing the *generic counterparts* of these interface, [`` IEnumerator`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator-1) and [`IEnumerable`1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable-1), given that these *derive from* their non-generic cousins.</sup>

<sup>[4] Here's the link to the [source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/9383f554a2c719af88010a66e2a283fa93c07db9/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/LanguagePrimitives.cs#L528), as of this writing (this logic is highly unlikely to change, however).</sup>

<sup>[5] Note that PowerShell only tests for the *non-generic* dictionary interface, [`System.Collections.IDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IDictionary), not also for its generic counterpart, [`` System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary-2). Since the latter does *not* derive from the former - unlike in the `IEnumerable` / `` IEnumerable`1 `` pair - types that implement *only* the generic interface unexpectedly *are* auto-enumerated; a prominent example is  [`System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject); see [GitHub issue #15204](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15204) for a discussion of this problematic behavior.</sup>