# How to type convert a derived class

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a PowerShell Object parser. In there, I have a `Path` class. something like:

```
Class MyPathClass {
    $CurrentPath = 'a', 'b', 'c'
    [string] ToString() {
        return $this.CurrentPath -Join '\'
    }
}

$MyPath = [MyPathClass]::new()
```

`$MyPath` returns:

```
CurrentPath
-----------
{a, b, c}
```

I would like the `MyPathClass` to automatically cast to a string when required.
For this I am using the [`PSTypeConverter` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pstypeconverter):

```
class MyPathConvertor : System.Management.Automation.PSTypeConverter
{
    [bool] CanConvertFrom([object]$sourceValue, [Type]$destinationType) {
        return $false
    }

    [object] ConvertFrom([object]$sourceValue, [Type]$destinationType, [IFormatProvider]$formatProvider, [bool]$ignoreCase) {
        return [NotImplementedException]::new()
    }

    [bool] CanConvertTo([object]$sourceValue, [Type]$destinationType) {
        return ($destinationType -eq [string])
    }

    [object] ConvertTo([object]$sourceValue, [Type]$destinationType, [IFormatProvider]$formatProvider, [bool]$ignoreCase) {
        return $SourceValue.ToString()
    }
}

Update-TypeData -TypeName MyPathClass -TypeConverter MyPathConvertor
```

So far, this works

```
"$MyPath"
a\b\c
```

But for a number of reasons (along with the fact that I do not want to display the "`CurrentPath`" property with the standard output), I derived the class from `System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]` (note that the path items in my project are actually `object` types and not `string` types):

```
Class MyPathClass : System.Collections.Generic.List[Object] {
    [string] ToString() {
        return $this -Join '\'
    }
}

$MyPath = [MyPathClass]::new()
$MyPath.Add('a')
$MyPath.Add('b')
$MyPath.Add('c')
```

```
$MyPath
a
b
c
```

```
$MyPath.ToString()
a\b\c
```

But for this I can't get the convertor to work.
Whatever I have tried so far, I always get:

```
"$MyPath"
a b c # expected: a\b\c
```

If even possible, how can I derive my class from `System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]` or get a similar display output for just `$MyPath` and automatically cast my class to a string for e.g. `"$MyPath"`?

---

Update in response to @sirtao's answer:

If I use @sirtao's [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77752227/1701026), I will get the property names as you define in your your class rather than the property names of the listed objects:

```
Class MyItemClass {
    $Type
    $Name
    $Value
    MyItemClass ($Type, $Name, $Value) {
        $this.Type  = $Type
        $this.Name  = $Name
        $this.Value = $Value
    }
}

$MyPath = [MyPathClass]::new()

$MyPath.Add(([MyItemClass]::new('a', 'b', 'c')))
$MyPath.Add(([MyItemClass]::new('d', 'e', 'f')))
$MyPath.Add(([MyItemClass]::new('g', 'h', 'i')))

$MyPath

Value
-----
{b, e, h}
```

Where I am looking for is an default display output for just `$MyPath` similar as using the `$MyPath.HiddenValue` property:

```
$MyPath.HiddenValue # Where I would like to do just: $MyPath

Type Name Value
---- ---- -----
a    b    c
d    e    f
g    h    i
```

And in case I *convert* `MyPathClass`  to a string (e.g. `"$MyPath"` or `[String]$MyPath`) I would expect something like (`return $this.HiddenValue.Name -join '\'`):

```
"The path is: $MyPath"
The path is: b\e\h
```

Comment: do you need your class to have all methods and properties from `List<T>` available or just `.Add` ? If not then its better to not inherit from it and use a hidden list as a field.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, actually the `List<T>` feature I am looking for is displaying a list of items by default (when I do just `$MyPath` without  quotes) and ***not*** display the embedded property as 'CurrentPath` (I do not care for its methods as `add`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You **don't need** to implement a **`System.Management.Automation.PSTypeConverter`** instance **for to-string conversion**:

  - PowerShell by defaults supports converting *any* type to `[string]`. See below for enumerables.
  - In classes that are "scalars" (non-enumerables), overriding the `.ToString()` method is therefore enough to control the stringification results.
- However, **if your class is considered *enumerable* by PowerShell, you do *not* get to control the stringification of its instances *as a whole***, only that of the *enumerated* elements.

  - What types PowerShell considers enumerable is primarily based on whether they implement the .NET [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IEnumerable) interface, but with selective exclusions and inclusions - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77687355/45375) for details.
  - **An instance of a type PowerShell considers enumerable is stringified as follows**:

    - The instance is enumerated and its *stringified elements* are joined with a separator to form a single string.

      - If the elements aren't already strings, they are stringified as they would be individually: by calling their `.ToString()` method, requesting culture-*invariant* representation, if supported via an overload.
    - That separator is a *space* by default, but can be overridden with the - rarely used and undefined-by-default - [`$OFS` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#ofs).

---

It follows from the above:

- **If you want to control the stringification behavior of your custom class' instances *as a whole*, the class must *not* implement `IEnumerable`**, which deriving from [`` System.Collections.Generic.List`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.List-1) *implicitly* does.
- Thus, you must **use a ["mixin"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) approach instead, where you store a `[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]` instance as an *instance variable***.

  - In PowerShell, any instance variable is invariably also a *public property* in .NET terms; while you can choose to mark it `hidden`, it is essentially a *convention* honored by *PowerShell only*.<sup>[1]</sup>
  - You're then free to either (selectively) implement wrapper methods, e.g. `.Add()`, that relay calls to the enclosed list or to access the enclosed list directly, as a property.
- The remaining challenge is **how to control the *default formatting* of your class instances, as rendered by PowerShell's [for-display output-formatting system](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/format/formatting-file-overview)**:

  - In order to have your class' instance rendered *as the enclosed list would*, you need to create a custom, out-of-band default view for it, as shown below.

    - Unfortunately, [`Update-FormatData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/update-formatdata), the cmdlet for updating formatting views, currently requires *XML*-based definitions provided via a (temporary) *file* - [GitHub issue #7845](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7845) asks for a simpler, in-memory, API-based alternative (which for *type data* already exists, via the `Update-TypeData` cmdlet).
    - Note: A type with an associated out-of-band view renders with that view even when used explicitly with `Format-*` cmdlets; however, you can use `-Force` to override it.
  - The solution below uses a *static constructor* to define the custom view on demand, namely when the first instance of the `MyPathClass` class is instantiated in a given session.

    - In the context of a [module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules), you'd bundle a formatting file (`*.ps1xml`) with it and load it via the `FormatsToProcess` entry in the module's [manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Module_Manifests).
  - The custom rendering is performed by the following command, where `$_` is the `MyPathClass` instance at hand, and `.List` is the property exposing the "mixed-in" list:

    ```bash
    ($_.List | Out-String) -replace '\r?\n\z'
    ```

    - This emulates the default formatting that would apply if `.List` were accessed directly, using [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string). Note the need for `-replace '\r?\n\z'` in order to eliminate the extra trailing newline that `Out-String` inexplicably adds - see [GitHub issue #14444](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14444).

```bash
Class MyPathClass {  

  # The "mixed-in" list instance.
  # You may choose to make this property `hidden`, but then you should
  # implement wrapper methods for manipulating the list, such as Add() below.
  $List = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]]::new()

  # Sample wrapper method for $List.Add()
  # However, .List.Add() ... may be called directly.
  Add($object) { $this.List.add($object) }

  # The string representation to use in stringification contexts, such as 
  # inside "...", casting to [string], and binding to [string]-typed parameters.
  [string]ToString() { return $this.List -join '\' }

  # Static constructor that defines the custom format view for
  # default rendering to the host (terminal).
  static MyPathClass() {
    # Dynamically defined a default, custom, out-of-band view that renders
    # the enclosed list.
    @'
<Configuration>
<ViewDefinitions>
      <View>
          <Name>MyPathClass</Name>
          <OutOfBand />
          <ViewSelectedBy>
              <TypeName>MyPathClass</TypeName>
          </ViewSelectedBy>
          <CustomControl>
              <CustomEntries>
                  <CustomEntry>
                     <CustomItem>
                          <ExpressionBinding>
                              <ScriptBlock>
                                <![CDATA[
($_.List | Out-String) -replace '\r?\n\z'
                                ]]>
                              </ScriptBlock>
                          </ExpressionBinding>
                      </CustomItem>
                  </CustomEntry>
              </CustomEntries>
          </CustomControl>
      </View>
</ViewDefinitions>
</Configuration>
'@ > ($tmpFile = [IO.Path]::GetTempPath() + "MyPathClass_${global:PID}.ps1xml")

    # Load the format data via -PrependPath, which *preempts* automatically loaded definitions, 
    # and clean up the temp. file
    Update-FormatData -PrependPath $tmpFile; Remove-Item $tmpFile

  }

}
```

---

<sup>[1] The `hidden` qualifier results in decorating a property with the [`System.Management.Automation.HiddenAttribute`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.HiddenAttribute) attribute. This hides the property from tab-completion, formatted output (even using `-Force` with the `Format-*` cmdlets doesn't work as an opt-in), `Get-Member` (by default, use `-Force` to include hidden properties), from `Select-Object` with wildcard names, and - inconsistently - from serialization commands: e.g., `Convert-Csv` ignores hidden properties, while `ConvertTo-Json` does not - see [GitHub issue #9847](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9847).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking I'm overthinking this, but it works keeping the actual value as obscured as possible, while giving out a `-join`ed `[String]` when called as such, otherwise a `List`

```
Class MyPathClass {
    hidden $HiddenValue = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]]::new()
    
    [void]Add($object) {
        $this.HiddenValue.add($object)
    }

    [string]ToString() {
        return $this.HiddenValue -join '\'
    }

    hidden [System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]]GetValue() {
        return $this.HiddenValue
    }

    
    static[hashtable[]]$MemberDefinitions = @(
        @{
            #DefaultDisplayPropertySet=@("Symbol","Degrees")
            MemberType = 'ScriptProperty'
            MemberName = 'Value'
            Value      = { $this.GetValue() }#Getter
        }
    )

    static MyPathClass() {
        $TypeName = [MyPathClass].Name

        foreach ($Definition in [MyPathClass]::MemberDefinitions) {
            Update-TypeData -TypeName $TypeName @Definition
        }
    }

};
```

OLD SOLUTION:
They way you have written it, your class is just a regular List with a different name.
Instead of extending the class, use it as hidden Property:

```
Class MyPathClass {
    hidden $HiddenValue=[System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]]::new()
    
    [void]Add($object){
        $this.HiddenValue.add($object)
    }

    [string]ToString(){
        return $this.HiddenValue -join '\'
    }

}
```

You'll have to write any other Method you need though.

Comment: For `$MyPath = [MyPathClass]::new()`, I actually want to see a difference between *displaying* `$MyPath` (without quotes) and *casting/converting* `"$MyPath"` (with quotes). But maybe I am oversimplifying my class and should just consider this approach.

Comment: Updated my answer to better fit your needs. Evaluate overloading `GetValue` to get whatever type of object you need

Comment: Thanks for the update, but the difference with your class and a class derived from `System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]` is that your class doesn't just show a list of items for `$MyPath` but adds its own property names (as e.g.  `Value`, defined by the `[MyPathClass]`) as an header. I have updated my question to be more clear for this direction.

Comment: as far as I know: you cannot. You need to have at least one non-hidden Property, and thus a header, to get what you want. But I am no authority.    

you might want to open a new question specifically asking how to format the default output of a Class instance, though.

Comment: @sirtao, the problem can be solved with a custom formatting view. Nice use of a static constructor, by the way.

Comment: @mklement0 thanks. I struggle to remember formatting views are a thing, I dislike having to rely on more files for a class than just the class file

Comment: Yes, the need for a file is unfortunate, and lifting this requirement is the subject of  [GitHub issue #7845](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7845) (I'm not holding my breath). As demonstrated, however, the file doesn't have to be persistent (and in a module context it is _appropriate_ to use a file).