# Why does $null behave differently in ForEach-Object {} vs foreach()?

Tags: .net, powershell, null, scalar

Considering the following examples:

#### `$null`

```
foreach ($n in $null) {'This is a $null test'}
(no output)

$null | ForEach-Object {'This is a $null test'}
This is a $null test

$null -in $null
True

$null -contains $null
True
```

#### `[int]1`

```
foreach ($n in [int]1) {'Test'}
Test

[int]1 | ForEach-Object {'Test'}
Test

[int]1 -in [int]1
True

[int]1 -contains [int]1
True
```

Since $null is a scalar value that contains nothing, in the second $null example, $null will send a single instance of 'nothing' down the pipeline, which explains the output.

Why can't `$null` be iterated over as a collection even though `$null -in $null` returns `True`?

- The performance gains from *not* iterating over evaluated null objects/values seem obvious, but why does PowerShell treat scalar variables/values as collections?
- Does this behavior persist through all of .NET and the .NET Framework?
- Is there type coercion happening or do I have an fundamental misunderstanding about how collections/lists are structured or behave?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr**

The asymmetry you've observed is definitely unfortunate - but is unlikely to get resolved, so as not to break backward compatibility (see the bottom section for a potential solution).

---

Both
`<commandOrExpression> | ...` (pipeline) and
`foreach ($var in <commandOrExpression>) { ... }`
are *enumeration contexts*:

- If `<commandOrExpression>` evaluates to an object that is *enumerable*,<sup>[1]</sup> it is automatically enumerated and *the enumerated elements are processed one by one*.
- If it doesn't, the result is processed as *itself*; in a manner of speaking: it is treated *like a single-element enumerable*.

---

- **`$null`**, which corresponds to `null` in C#, is a special *something* that happens to *represent* a "scalar (single) nothing".
- This contrasts with the ***enumerable null*** - technically the `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value` singleton, aka "Automation Null" - which is what you get when a command produces *no output*.

  - It is a PS-specific representation of an *enumerable* that is *nothing in itself* and also *has no elements*: Its purpose is to signal "I represent nothing - I am not an object myself (unless I'm forced to act as one (as a scalar) in *expressions*, in which case I'll pretend to be `$null`), and enumerating me produces *no* elements".
- As an aside: as of PowerShell 7.4.x it is still nontrivial to determine if a given stored value is an actual `$null` or an enumerable null (a distinction that situationally *does* matter):

  ```bash
  # Only $true if $someValue contains the enumerable null 
  $null -eq $someValue -and @($someValue).Count -eq 0
  ```

  - The following future enhancement has been green-lit, but has not yet been implemented - see [GitHub issue #13465](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13465#issuecomment-1377486490):

    ```bash
    # !! Future enhancement - doesn't work as of v7.4.x
    $someValue -is [System.Management.Automation.AutomationNull]
    ```

---

Therefore, both the `foreach` loop and the pipeline:

- fortunately do *not* perform enumeration if the *enumerable null* is provided as input, given that its very purpose is to signal that there is *nothing to enumerate*.

  ```bash
  # Capture the output of a command that produces NO output.
  $noOutput = Get-Item *NoSuchFile*

  # No output, because the loop body is not executed.
  foreach ($obj in $noOutput) { 'This does not print.' }

  # Ditto.
  $noOutput | ForEach-Object { 'This does not print' }
  ```
- *should* process `$null` as *itself*, and therefore result in a single processing iteration with `$null` as the (non-)object to process:

  - Fortunately, this *is* how it works in the [*pipeline*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipelines), as evidenced by your sample call to [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet* in your question.
  - *Unfortunately*, this is *not* how the [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) *language statement* behaves, which unexpectedly does *not* process the `$null`, as you've also observed.

---

As for the *reason* for this asymmetry:

- Up to version 2 of Windows PowerShell, assigning the output from a command that produced *no* output to a *variable* implicitly - and unexpectedly - converted the enumerable null (representing the lack of output) to `$null`, which caused the following statements *not* to be equivalent:

  ```bash
  # DIRECT processing of command output - the loop body is NOT entered.
  foreach ($obj in Get-Item *NoSuchFile*) { 'This does not print' }

  # INDIRECT processing of command output, via an *intermediate variable*.
  $output = Get-Item *NoSuchFile*
  # In v2, $output was $null, not the enumerable null,
  # causing the loop body to execute (once, with $obj containing $null)
  # In v3+, this is now - fortunately - equivalent to the above.
  foreach ($obj in $output) { 'This does not print' }
  ```
- In v3, two fundamental changes were made:

  - Variables now *do* store the enumerable null as such, without quietly converting it to `$null`.
  - It was decided to ignore `$null` as `foreach` input:<sup>[2]</sup>
- Given the former v3 change, implementing the latter was *not* strictly necessary, but *presumably*:

  - The latter change was motivated by also making *non-existent* variables result in *no* processing.
  - The assumption was made that if a *pipeline* is used, intermediate and therefore potentially non-existent variables *aren't needed*, in which case the problem doesn't arise.
- However, the problem (still) *does* arise *in the pipeline*, namely if *non-existent variables* or *non-existent properties* of existing objects are used as input, because they evaluate to `$null` and therefore (justifiably) cause `$null` to be sent through the pipeline.
  Also, passing the enumerable null as an *argument* to a function or script's untyped parameter causes quiet conversion to `$null`.

---

It follows from the above that a *potential solution* that should only minimally impact backward compatibility, if at all, is the following:

- Make references to non-existent variables or properties default to the *enumerable null* rather than `$null`, which would implicitly prevent enumeration in both the pipeline and in `foreach` statements.
  Additionally, preserve the enumerable null as function / script arguments when binding to untyped parameters.

  - In *expression* contexts, the enumerable null behaves like `$null`, so something like `$null -eq $noSuchVariable` would continue to work.
- Make `foreach` too process *actual* `$null` values as such, as the pipeline already does, which would eliminate the asymmetry.

---

<sup>[1] Specifically, types that implement the [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IEnumerable) interface or its generic counterpart are automatically enumerated, but there are a few exceptions: strings, dictionaries (types implementing `IDictionary` or its generic counterpart), and `System.Xml.XmlNode` instances. Additionally, `System.Data.DataTable` is enumerated too, despite not implementing `IEnumerable` itself, via its `.Rows` property.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77687355/45375) for details.</sup>

<sup>[2] This change in behavior in v3 was announced on the PowerShell team blog in 2012: [New V3 Language Features](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/new-v3-language-features/), section, section "ForEach statement does not iterate over $null",</sup>

Comment: Don't know where we'd all be without your insights, @mklement0 :-)  Thanks for an incredibly helpful answer.

Comment: I'm glad to hear the answer helped, @Paulπ, and I appreciate the nice feedback. I've added some more details to the answer.

Comment: Great answer as ever :-). Additional historical tidbit: way back in PowerShell 2.0, ```foreach``` apparently *did* used to iterate once when ```$null``` was provided as the "collection" expression - see https://serverfault.com/a/457760/563962

Comment: Thank you, @mclayton, also for the nice feedback. The intermediate-variable example was actually meant to highlight this, but didn't do a good enough job. I've amended the answer, and I've added a footnote with a link to the what's-new-in-v3 blog post.