# Index out of Range exception with null returned from a static function

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I get a strange exception on calling a static function that return a null object:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the
collection.
Parameter name: index
At H:\test\issue_nullret.ps1:12 char:5
+     [CmdUtils]::RunCommand($cmd)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentOutOfRangeExce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

The script is:

```
class CmdUtils {
  static [object]RunCommand($cmd)
  {
      $res = .$cmd
      #### if ($res -eq $null) { $res = $null } ### uncommenting this fixes it, but why ??
      return $res
  }
}

function RunCmd($cmd)
{
    [CmdUtils]::RunCommand($cmd) ### this errors out at the [ ] brackets
}

RunCmd {write-host 'Hi'}
```

I am using Powershell 5.1 on Windows 7.
It'd be great if someone could offer an explanation of what happens here, or if this behaviour pertains on PS 7.4 and is just a known bug.

Comment: this got fixed in pwsh 7. can say that i've seen this error before, but my guess is that in 5.1 it doesn't know how to coerce automation null into null. my advice to solve this would be to use `.Invoke()` as it will always return `Collection<>`. Then you're function will implicitly enumerate it, so: `static [object] RunCommand($cmd) { return $cmd.Invoke() }`

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30016949/why-and-how-are-these-two-null-values-different) is related but since it causes PS to throw an exception where it shouldn't I think it's not a duplicate.

Comment: *Does this answer your question?* Actually no because it's a situation where Powershell throws an exception that shouldn't even happen. The code is not dealing with arrays at all. @KenWhite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior you're observing is a bug in Windows PowerShell 5.1 that has since been fixed in newer versions of [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell). An easy way to reproduce this error:

```bash
class Test { static [object] Testing() { return & { } } }
[Test]::Testing()
```

From here we can can check the exception's StackTrace:

```bash
PS ..\> $Error[0].Exception.StackTrace

   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeAsMemberFunctionT[T](Object instance, Object[] args)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
```

Right after throwing the out of range exception we can see a call for `InvokeAsMemberFunctionT[T](Object instance, Object[] args)`, and if we check the source code for this method in PowerShell 7+ ([scriptblock.cs#L543-L548](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/ec8c163369ae44d45fbb7668ec216f94dc6ae8c9/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/lang/scriptblock.cs#L543-L548)) we can see the following:

```cs
// This is needed only for the case where the
// method returns [object]. If the argument to 'return'
// is a pipeline that emits nothing then result.Count will
// be zero so we catch that and "convert" it to null. Note that
// the return statement is still required in the method, it
// just receives nothing from it's argument.
if (result.Count == 0)
{
    return default(T);
}
```

So they have essentially fixed the bug by doing what you have found by yourself as a workaround :)

There is also reference GitHub issue for this bug: [Fix for #7128 Methods with return type [object] should return null for an empty result #7138](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/7138).

In summary, this error occurs on methods having a return type of `[object]` where the argument is a script block, which, when invoked returns [`AutomationNull.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-null?view=powershell-7.3#empty-null).

---

Personally, to solve this specific issue, I would use [`ScriptBlock.Invoke()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.invoke?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0), this method ensures return type will be `Collection<PSObject>` from there the collection gets enumerated when outputted from your function without issues. But note, the use of `.Invoke()` is not always recommended, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59220711/45375) for more details.

```bash
class CmdUtils {
    static [object] RunCommand([scriptblock] $cmd) {
        return $cmd.Invoke()
    }
}

function RunCmd([scriptblock] $cmd) {
    [CmdUtils]::RunCommand($cmd)
}

RunCmd { Write-Host 'Hi' }
```

Comment: @mklement0 I see what you mean. Yes, I agree. I've updated my answer to make that clear. Thanks