# PowerShell 5.1 : Where-Object returns an empty object that equals null

Tags: powershell, null

I am working on a script in PowerShell 5.1 and I got a issue that I cannot really make sense of :

```
@{test=@() | Where-Object {$_ -ne $null}} | ConvertTo-Json -Compres
```

returns

```json
{"test":{}}
```

Yet

```
$null -eq (@() | Where-Object {$_ -ne $null})
```

is `True`

Why does `ConvertTo-Json` returns an empty object on a null pipe result ?

Comment: Because PowerShell and `$null` have a weird relationship. An empty enumeration isn't quite, precisely, exactly the same as `$null` in all circumstances, even though PowerShell will usually pretend quite adequately that it is. Instead it's really a `System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull`. Explicitly converting to `[psobject]` will coerce it to a true `$null` (so `@{test=[psobject] (@() | Where-Object {$_ -ne $null})}`). Note that this is fixed in PowerShell 7.2.5 without requiring an explicit conversion (and probably earlier, but I can't find the issue).

Comment: this by itself isn't proper to being with: `test=@() | Where-Object {$_ -ne $null}`.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala: but that's not what's being used here -- `@{test=@() | Where-Object {$_ -ne $null}}` is a perfectly valid expression that creates a hash table with a single key named `test` (and a value that's an `AutomationNull`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert, the original bug report is https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9231, and it seems the issue was fixed in 7.0. I encourage you to write up your comment as an answer.

Comment: @mklement0: I might have known that would be one of yours. :)

Comment: @JeroenMostert :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues at play here. First, an empty pipeline is not the same thing as `$null`, as explained in ["Why is an empty PowerShell pipeline not the same as null?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22343187/4137916) `@{test=@() | Where-Object {$_ -ne $null}}` produces a hash table with a `test` key that has an `AutomationNull` value, not `$null`.

Second, there's a bug in PowerShell prior to 7.0 where `AutomationNull` is serialized as an empty object rather than `$null`, as reported in ["ConvertTo-Json unexpectedly serializes `AutomationValue.Null` as an empty object, not null"](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9231) (powershell#9231).

To work around this bug in older versions, you can coerce the `AutomationNull` to a real `$null` by inserting a `psobject` cast, which will then result in the value serializing properly:

```
@{test=[psobject](@() | Where-Object {$_ -ne $null})} | ConvertTo-Json -Compres
```